# LTE vs 3G power cost at low speed

Tags: power, gsm, power-consumption, 3g

I am currently working on a device in which I need to implement internet connection. For that I intend to use a GSM module, for example this one: [SIM5320](http://simcom.ee/modules/wcdma-hspa/sim5320/). This is a 3G module. I have been reading about 3G vs LTE power consumption comparison (this is a good one: [Comparing LTE and 3G Energy Consumption](https://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer/docs/best-practices/comparing-lte-and-3g-energy-consumption)) and it seems that LTE consumes more power. I however, dint intend to use high throughput here. I just need the least power hungry module. I have heard a rumor that at low transmission speeds LTE module would be less power hungry, but I cannot find any data to back this up.

Is that a true statement? I would appreciate all help regarding the topic.

Comment: If you are power-constrained it would be best to use LTE Cat M1 or NB IoT.

Comment: That would be great, but I am concerned that this technology is not yet mature. Also, it seems like it is designed for "in building use". My application will work outdoors. When I think of it now it shouldnt be a concern. Here for example, there are no prices yet: https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/sara-r4-series . Also it seems there is no 2G/3G fallback.

Comment: It is just designed for better range/lower power than normal LTE and works excellent outdoors. Price of a module is around 12 USD now for NB IoT. Soon there are going to be "multi-system" modules available from Simcon (GPRS/3G/4G/LTE/NB IoT) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soVA0sA6FaM